# Using <a> tag or <button> tag for dropdown menues | bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

We're using bootstrap in our project, and when we use dropdown we are asked to change our menu items from `<a href="#" ..` to `<button>` instead. Even tho the documentation for bootstraps use `<a href ..`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

I've asked the UX designer, and it has some issues with focus tabbing, like. when you tab through elements.

Is there any other compelling reason to use `<button>` over `<a href="# ..`

Comment: depends on the semantics I guess - if you are binding an onclick and the click goes nowhere but opens a drop down, then I guess a button is more semantically correct, if you are using it to link to another part of the page or somewhere else, then an anchor would be correct - both should be able to be tabbed to though

Comment: 'a' tag is supposed to link somewhere - other page or section on the page. That's why in js it needs preventDefault() to suppress this behaviour on click event. But 'button' tag doesn't need that, hence button makes a bit more sense for dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use buttons in a dropdown, too:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example: https://www.bootply.com/NTH6FzGx4A

Comment: href is not a valid attribute for the button tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: thats right, but he could bind a function to the onclick-event, instead. i've just wanted to show, that the dropdown will work with buttons, too.